# Bash variable is empty depending on cron schedule frequency. If every 1, 5, 15, or 10 minutes, there is a value. If every 30 or top of hour, empty

Tags: shell-script, cron, environment-variables

I've got a cron scheduled bash script I am seeing odd behavior with. As the title says, there is a single variable that is either empty or not after the script runs depending on the cron schedule. If I run it every minute with `* * * * *` or `*/1 * * * *`, the variable is filled and the script works. The same goes for every 5, 10, or 15 minutes. As soon as I move it to 30 minutes with as `*/30 * * * *` or at the top of every hour with `0 * * * *`, the variable is empty.

The script itself does not use time in any way other than to append the output of 'date' to a file before appending the value of the variable to that same file.

The script works as expected when executed manually. I'd like it to run at the top of every hour or every 30 minutes, but when I make only those changes in cron, the script fails with the empty variable.

I am at a loss for how cron frequency can impact a script this way. The script is static. Only the cron entry is changing. Ideas? Thanks in advance.

Script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# declare variables
resultsdir="/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Ian/Documents/IT/Speedtest"
dl="00.00"
#run the download speedtest and grep the Mbit/s result into $dl
dl=$(speedtest --no-upload | grep bit)
#if the $dl variable is empty notify and exit
if [ -z "$dl" ]
then
      /sbin/notice_log_tool -a "Speedtest failed due to empty dl variable" --severity=6
      exit
else
      :
fi
#append the date and time to speedtest.txt
date>>$resultsdir/speedtest.txt
#append the download speed after the date to speedtest.txt
echo $dl>>$resultsdir/speedtest.txt
#append the speedtest Mbit/s numerics to speedtest_numerics.txt
echo $dl | tr -d ' aA-zZ:/'>>$resultsdir/speedtest_numerics.txt
#notify of script completion
/sbin/notice_log_tool -a "Speedtest completed - ${dl}." --severity=6
exit
```

working cron entry example:

```
* * * * * /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/TFTP/Scripts/speedtest.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

failing cron entry example:

```
*/30 * * * * /share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/TFTP/Scripts/speedtest.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

An example of what goes into the var `$dl` for grep to match on during a successful run:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration... 
Testing from ISP (IP)... 
Retrieving speedtest.net server list... 
Selecting best server based on ping... 
Hosted by ISP [response]  
Testing download speed...
Download: X Mbit/s
```

What goes into the var `$dl` when the job is run at `0 * * * *` or `*/30 * * * *`:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration... 
Testing from ISP (IP)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
```

The script continues before `speedtest` completes per my definition of complete. Perhaps there is a timeout of some sort. There are only about 10 jobs that run on the hour or half-hour throughout the day, so I don't think it is a load issue. Performance metrics look good. The box's main job is being my NAS and Plex Media Server, so I'd say 95 percent of any given day it is idle. There are no scheduled cloud backups, etc.

I have scheduled it to run every minute and it will run successfully except for on the hour and half hour.

It could be scheduled differently or `speedtest` could run repeatedly until it grabs a download metric, but that is a work around without identifying the cause.

Comment: What is the name of the variable and how exactly is that variable used in the script (show code, ideally an example that reproduces the issue)?

Comment: I added the exact script and cron entry examples to the original question for review

Comment: Debugging advice: try piping the whole stdout and stderr to file `speedtest ... >/tmp/speedtest.out 2>/tmp/speedtest.err` so that you can take a look at what's actually happening when the variable is empty. You can still do the regular `grep` on the file: `dl=$(grep bit /tmp/speedtest.out)`.

Comment: `tr -d ' aA-zZ:/'` probably deletes more characters than you expect.

Comment: Hold on, where is the script failing? Is it failing in the `if` statement because `$dl` is empty, or does it fail in writing anything to the `speedtest_numerics.txt` output file because of the faulty `tr`?

Comment: Add debug by changing line 6 to `dl=$(speedtest --no-upload  | tee -a /tmp/speedtest.out | grep bit)`. How many other cron jobs start at 0 and 30 mins? It is possible that cron prioritises more frequent tasks over others (on the basis an hourly task is less likely to over-run itself). You might try a `sleep 17` early in the script to defer the speed test off that prized 00 seconds slot.

Comment: As others said, better debug what's going on. Specifically capture the output in a temporary file, then grep its contents instead of directly grepping.

Comment: It seems the script continues before `speedtest` completes. There is no 'Download: X Mbit/s' for grep to match, which leaves the variable blank.

If I take `grep` out, I get this in the var/stdout: 
'Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from ISP (IP)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...'

A complete test should include:

'Hosted by ISP [response]
Testing download speed...
`Download: X Mbit/s`'

Speedtest doesn't timeout because it gives an error I'd see. There are about 10 jobs that run at 0 of any hour daily.

Comment: You're not alone. Try running at 5 and 35. https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/7xxdoj/does_anyone_else_have_speedtestcli_fail_precisely/

Comment: @roaima, I can definitely see a speedtest host filtering that traffic at certain times to avoid an accidental DOS and force users to distribute the tests over time. I can certainly offset the schedule, but I would like to know what the root cause is.

Comment: @zeeohsix, if we're looking at the `dl=$(speedtest --no-upload | grep bit)` line, then no, the script doesn't continue until `speedtest` finishes. (Or if it does, your shell is broken, but that would be more unexpected.) If it's indeed `speedtest` failing due to some external issue, one would _hope_ it'd be kind enough to print an error message (which should end up in your logs or in the email output from `cron`), but even if it does, `speedtest | grep bit` might still end up giving an empty output.

Comment: Also, wrt. it working with `* * * * *` but not `*/30 * * * *`, check if it still works on the hour with the first one, or if it only works 29 times out of 30, failing at xx:00 and xx:30 in that case too.

Comment: The speedtest does not complete on the hour our half-hour mark regardless of the interval. I added some code to start tcpdump before the speedtest and grab netstat output using the PID. Netstat comes up empty when the test doesn't complete, and of course, so does the tcpdump. When the test isn't on the hour or half-hour, I get the netstat entry for speedtest and the tcpdump capture is the tcp data transfer of the test. This leads me to believe it is a local issue.